# Why have android:actionLayout and android:icon at the same time?

Tags: android

I am reading about action bars in BusyCoder's Android guide. There is an example:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/add"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/add"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/add"/>
```

What is the point to have both `android:actionLayout` and `android:icon` defined? What are the conditions when the icon would show up?

Thanks for helping out Android noob

Answer (score 3):

> What are the conditions when the icon would show up?

I can't rule out the possibility that the action bar will decide that there is not enough room for the `actionLayout`, but there is enough room for an action item, which would therefore show the icon. Also, with ActionBarSherlock, the icon is shown even in the overflow on Android 2.x devices, and so again if the `actionLayout` would be too large, the icon might get used. Also, if I used `ifRoom|collapseActionView` instead of just `ifRoom`, the icon would be used.

That being said:

- My sample does not actually watch for this theoretical action item, should it appear, to do anything if the user clicks on it
- I am guessing at possible action bar behavior, as I have not tried any experiments to force the action bar to decide whether there is enough room for all `actionLayout`-configured items

Answer (score 2):

here `android:icon` is defined to supply an icon for your menu item. This is always optional but it is recommended to have an icon for the menu item.

`android:actionLayout` is defined to supply a custom view for the menu item again this is optional but if u need some Image Views, Text Views, Edit Text Views etc. in your menu item, this is the way to go.

If you need more help see these guides. These I think will be more helpful to you.

[Action Bar Android Developer Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)

[Menu Resource Android Developer Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html)

Also take a look at this example. This may give you a much better idea about android Action bars.

vimaltuts.com/android-tutorial-for-beginners/android-action-bar-tab-menu-example

```
                        Thank You!
```