# onClick in onCreateActionMode

Tags: android

I have added actionLayout to my contextbar menu items, now it is not clickable anymore, I have added the onClick handler but no luck yet.

Menu items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- highlight swatches -->
    <item
            android:orderInCategory="1"
            android:id="@+id/highlight_item_1"
            android:title="Highlight yellow"
            android:showAsAction="always"
            android:actionLayout="@layout/highlight_action_layout"
            android:minWidth="2dp"/>
</menu>
```

Menu item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:id="@+id/higlight_layout">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/menu_img"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_highlights_yellow"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/menu_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="C1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/menu_img"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

onClick handler:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_reader_contextual_actions, menu);

        menu.findItem(0).getActionView().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.i("", "");
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: return boolean, but you should be getting compilation error

Answer (score 0):

Try-

```
 @Override
 public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {

 // Inflate a menu resource providing context menu items
 MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();

 inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_reader_contextual_actions, menu);
 final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.your_item_id);
 item.getActionView().setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {   
    Log.i("", "");
    }
  });
    return true;
}
```

**NOTE:** You have to use item id in place of 0 for `menu.findItem`.

**UPDATE:**

Better use `onActionItemClicked` -

> public abstract boolean **onActionItemClicked** (ActionMode mode,
>   MenuItem item)
>
> Added in API level 11 Called to report a user click on an action
>   button.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> *mode*    The current ActionMode
>
> *item*    The item that was clicked
>
> **Returns**
>
> true if this callback handled the event, false if the standard
>   MenuItem invocation should continue.

Example -

```
// Called when the user selects a contextual menu item
 @Override
 public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
   switch (item.getItemId()) {
   case R.id.your_item_id:
   doSomething();
   mode.finish(); // Action picked, so close the CAB
   return true;

   default:
   return false;
   }
 }
```

Comment: I am in a public class SelectActionModeCallback implements ActionMode.Callback, there is no onCreateOptionsMenu

Comment: Updated for onCreateActionMode.

Comment: When I set android:actionLayout on an item, onActionItemClicked is never called for that item neither does the onClickListner :(

Comment: Really don't know but this is the desired way to do so. Check  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12939627/passing-id-of-listview-item-to-actionmode-callback-object and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16968499/why-have-androidactionlayout-and-androidicon-at-the-same-time